# Python SSLError when server is Linux, but no errors when on Mac OSX

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, python-3.7

Using asyncio + Python 3.7.2, running into some very strange issues...

When the server is Linux-based (Ubuntu), I hit an SSL-related error:

```
SSL error in data received
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7f0ad36d27b8>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=9 read=polling write=<idle, bufsize=0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 526, in data_received
ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 207, in feed_ssldata
self._sslobj.unwrap()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 767, in unwrap
return self._sslobj.shutdown()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: KRB5_S_INIT] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2605)
```

The program continues to run, but it causes a failure on the client side as it appears that the connection is closed

From Client:

```
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

This does not occur when the Server is being served from MacOSX...

What/How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you have some code to share ?